# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre Confiscar, Incautar, Requisar, Embargar y Decomisar?

Tags: significado

¿Qué diferencia hay entre esas palabras, aparentemente sinónimas?
Confiscar, Incautar, Requisar. E incluso embargar y decomisar.

Las definiciones de la RAE son demasiado simples y similares, y si consulto otros diccionarios cada uno dice una cosa diferente.

Todas implican que la "autoridad" te quite algo.
Y según en que diccionario lo consulte te dicen cosas como que...
*Incautar* y *decomisar* parece que se dicen cuando está relacionado con una actividad delictiva. Pero no veo la diferencia entre ellas.
De *requisar* dice tanto que se hace por interés público como por ser una mercancía prohibida.
*Embargar* puede que implique una orden judicial, las otras quizás no. Y quizás no implique que te quiten algo para siempre, podrían simplemente tenerlo retenido. Aparentemente es la más diferente, suele utilizarse "me han embargado el piso y el coche".

¿En qué contexto es más correcto usar cada una de estas palabras?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque en ocasiones se usan de manera más o menos indistinta, sobre todo en un contexto informal, la diferencia está en el motivo por el que te lo quitan. Por otra parte, en algunos casos, una ley puede necesitar hacer uso de conceptos similares, pero no idénticos, y a veces usa para ello palabras que en otros casos son sinónimas. Estas respuestas se aplican a España:

**Confiscar** algo es muy general. Yo diría que todo aquello que sea hacerse con un bien de una persona sin su consentimiento por motivos considerados legítimos es *confiscar*.

**Incautarse** de algo (o *incautar* algo, informal) es tomar posesión de ello la autoridad. Aquí, la *posesión* se refiere a la tenencia física de una cosa, no a su propiedad legal. Suele usarse en el ámbito penal. La policía puede incautarse de bienes cuya tenencia por particulares es ilícita, o que se sospecha que están relacionados con un delito. Eso no quiere decir que esos bienes pasen a ser propiedad del Estado, solo que la policía los va a custodiar mientras dure la investigación y, en su caso, el juicio.

**Decomisar** algo es acordar su comiso, que es su adjudicación definitiva al Estado, con pérdida de los derechos que tuviera el anterior propietario, como consecuencia de un delito. Por ejemplo, en una sentencia puede acordarse el comiso de la droga que en su día fue incautada, de los bienes comprados con los beneficios de un delito, etc.

**Requisar** un bien determinado es tomarlo la autoridad para sí, ya sea de forma temporal o permanente, para hacer uso de él por el bien común.

**Expropiar** algo es muy similar a *requisar*, pero implica que el bien pasa a ser propiedad de la autoridad, y por lo general que esta indemniza al anterior titular por la pérdida (en el caso de la requisa puede haber indemnización o no). Por otra parte, *requisar* suele usarse para situaciones de emergencia, mientras que *expropiar* normalmente es algo que se hace con más tiempo.

**Embargar** un bien es tomar posesión de él una autoridad (no tiene por qué ser un órgano judicial, en España también embargan las agencias tributarias autonómicas y la estatal, y la Seguridad Social) para saldar una deuda (ya sea subastando el bien o quedándoselo para sí la autoridad, y ya sea la deuda con la propia autoridad o con terceros). El embargo de un bien no implica necesariamente la pérdida definitiva de todo el valor del bien: en ocasiones puede recuperarse el bien pagando el importe de la deuda, y en otras ocasiones el bien se subasta y luego se devuelve a su propietario la cantidad obtenida, restándole el importe de la deuda y los gastos ocasionados.

Comment: Me llama la atención la forma "incautarse de". En Argentina usamos "incautar algo", como transitivo.

Comment: En España se usan las dos, pero la formal es "incautarse de".